# Trying to implement Dynamic Values with React-JSS

Tags: css, reactjs, dynamic, jss

My team uses this CSS library with our React project: https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.1.1#dynamic-values

I'm trying to utilize two dynamic values like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {createUseStyles} from 'react-jss'

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  duration: (height, marginTop) => ({
    marginTop: marginTop,
    height: height
  })
});

const Appointment = ({companyName, vehicleId, duration, isHalfHour=false}) => {
  const height = (duration / 0.6).toString().concat('%');
  const marginTop = isHalfHour ? '20px' : '0';  // Note: 20px is 50% of timeContainer.height
  const classes = useStyles(height, marginTop);

  return (
    <div className={classes.duration}>
      Sample Text
    </div>
  )
};
```

What's interesting is that when I just had the `height` variable, everything worked fine.  I now want to also pass in `marginTop`.  `height` is still respected but it ignores `marginTop`.

I even hardcoded things like this:

```
const classes = useStyles(height, '20px');
```

But that didn't solve the problem.

So I'm curious what I'm doing wrong such that the 2nd parameter into the `duration` style isn't used?

Answer (score 1):

Just before heading to sleep, I tried one last thing: I kept wondering why only the first parameter was accepted and the second one was ignored.  So I changed the parameter name to `props` and then passed in: `{height, marginTop}` and voila, it worked!!!

Long Day!

Answer (score 0):

there is is only one argument that you pass to `useStyles(object)`